# How to synchronize database files between multiple clients on node.js server without download those files that are already downloaded?

Tags: node.js, server, client

I'm making a node.js application with a MySQL database, and there are string fields in some tables that represent paths in the filesystem for example: `"C:\Users\steve\Desktop\my-nodejs-app\files\Apple.jpg"` and when a client connects to the server for the first time automatically download all the files in those paths in the database. Every client can add registers and send files in the server.

My question is: 
Let's suppose that two clients use the app regularly and client1 adds a new file in the files folder. In the client1's folder it will be all the files updated, but then client2 connects in the app and it has all the files but doesn't have the new file added.

How can I fix this? Make an app where a client just download those files that don't have and don't download all the files every time it connects to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest having the client request a list of all files on "connect", then loop through them to see if they exist locally.  If they don't, request/download them from the server.